# Better way (or correct way) to receive values in functions in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie :PP, I have a function call "Search", this function received 2 values, theme and q, after the user to choise the type and to insert the key word in field box, the user click in submit.
I can see these values in function search, but not in index, so I'm using a global variable :PP

But is ugly, there is a better way?

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :require_user

 def index
  @theme = $a
  @value = $b
 end


 def search
  $a = params[:theme]
  $b = params[:q]
  redirect_to :root
 end
end
```

views/welcome/_search.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'search', :method => 'get') do %>

<div style="background:#fafafa; color:#222; padding:10px;">
<h4>Pesquisa Avançada</h4>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" class="css-checkbox">
        <% [ 'Analista', 'Estagiário' ].each do |theme| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme, :class => "radio"%>
          <%= theme %><br>
        <% end %>
      </input>
    <td><%= text_field_tag :q, nil, :placeholder => 'Palavra-chave' %>  
    <%= submit_tag("Pesquisar") %></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<% end %>

<% if @theme == "Analista"%>
  <%= render "search_systems_analyst" %>
<% elsif @theme == "Estagiário" %>
  <%= render "search_intern" %>
<% end %>
```

Ps: Sorry for my english

Comment: do not use global variable. because in mean there is another request your global variable will be update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
redirect_to :root_path(theme: params[:theme], q: params[:q])
```

Comment: Appeared a syntax error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
    redirect_to :root_path(theme: params[:theme], value: params[:q]), but I understood the idea o /, will try to fix it and I'll be back posting is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lorena,

You have to pass in the redirect_to like NitinJ said.

```
redirect_to :root_path, theme: params[:theme], q: params[:q]
```

You are sending to the action search "params[:theme] and params[:q]" from your GET request, but you aren't sending these params to your index action